# I wonder how (ar1 | ar2 [I]) works in this code

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
let n = 6;

let arr1 = [46, 33, 33, 22, 31, 50];
let arr2 = [27, 56, 19, 14, 14, 10];

let answer;

let solution = (n, arr1, arr2) => {
  answer = arr1.map(
    (arr1, i) =>
      (arr1 | arr2[i])
        .toString(2)
        .padStart(n, 0)
        .replace(/0/g, " ")
        .replace(/1/g, "#"),
    console.log(arr2)
  );
  console.log(answer);
};
solution(n, arr1, arr2);
```

I'm asking because there is something I don't understand in the code above.
How did (arr1 | arr2[i]) work?
Why are the two arrays combined?

Comment: `|` is the bit-wise OR operator, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR

Comment: `|` is a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) operator. Why that is there, in that code... Who knows? What's that code supposed to do?

Comment: I don't understand how it does anything at all, given that the `=>` callback to `.map()` appears to return `undefined` (because of the `console.log()`).

Comment: _"Why are the two arrays combined?"_ - they aren't. `arr1` at _that_ point is not the array, it is one element - the one passed into the callback function by `arr1.map`. So this is a bit-wise OR of the current element of array 1, and the `arr2[i]` element from the second one. And since `i` is the index of the current array1 element, `arr2[i]` accesses the corresponding element in the other, that has the same index.

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate of "What does the '|' (single pipe) do in JavaScript"? That only answers part of the question. There's more to this one - the confusion over the map function re-using the same variable name `arr1`, as @CBroe pointed out. This question is a good example of a complex use of the bitwise or operator, and should be given a chance to be answered properly.

Comment: @isherwood please review again with this in mind

Comment: Fair enough, but the rest of the question is mostly speculation, right? It doesn't seem answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bitwise or" is the name of the `|` operator. JavaScript coerces `arr1` and `arr2[i]` to binary (a set of 0s and/or 1s), then *or*s them.

For a given set of bits, the bitwise operator evaluates them like this:

```
(0 | 0) === 0
(0 | 1) === 1
(1 | 0) === 1
(1 | 1) === 1
```

`arr1.map(arr1, i)...` creates a locally scoped variable `arr1` with the same name as the array it's mapping. So, inside the map function, `arr1` refers to the item at array index `i`. It should be renamed for clarity.

`arr2[i]` just evaluates to the value from the 2nd array, which is in the same position during the map's loop. So, in this case, for a given index of the loop:

| `i` | `arr1` | `arr2[i]` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 46 | 27 |
| 1 | 33 | 56 |
| 2 | 33 | 19 |
| 3 | 22 | 14 |
| 4 | 31 | 14 |
| 5 | 50 | 10 |

Then the confusing part of your code (`(arr1 | arr2[i])`) does a bitwise or on the binary values:

| arr1 | Number(arr1).toString(2) | arr2[i] | Number(arr2[i]).toString(2) | Bitwise Or (binary) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | 101110 | 27 | 011011 | 111111 |
| 33 | 100001 | 56 | 111000 | 111001 |
| 33 | 100001 | 19 | 010011 | 110011 |
| 22 | 010110 | 14 | 001110 | 011110 |
| 31 | 011111 | 14 | 001110 | 011111 |
| 50 | 110010 | 10 | 001010 | 111010 |

Then your code `.toString(2).padStart(n, 0).replace(/0/g, " ").replace(/1/g, "#")` just uses the binary values above and replaces zeroes with spaces, and ones with octothorpes: `['######', '###  #', '##  ##', ' #### ', ' #####', '### # ']`